# phone number regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form with an input that follows this pattern:

```
pattern='(\+|00)\d{2,3}[-]\d{8,10}'
```

an example would be `+999-123456789`

I have to form validate it again using javascript and have tried to convert the pattern into a Regex, the example passes the pattern but fails passing the regex. Any idea as to why?

```
var check = /^([00|+])([0-9]{2,3})[-]?([0-9]{8,10})$/;
```

Comment: Why don't you do the same check? `/^(\+|00)\d{2,3}-\d{8,10}$/.test('+999-123456789'); // true`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RaKZg/ your regex seems to pass your sample string, although as @Pointy mentioned, it wont work with double zeroes leading

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect.  This:

```
[00|+]
```

is equivalent to

```
[0|+]
```

and means "match a single character that's either '0', '|', or '+'." I think you want:

```
var check = /^(00|\+)(\d{2,3})-(\d{8,10)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your pattern tranferred to a RegEx: `/(\+|00)\d{2,3}-{0,1}\d{8,10}$/`.  Example below.

```js
var number = '+999-123456789';

if (number.match(/(\+|00)\d{2,3}-{0,1}\d{8,10}$/)) {
  alert('Phone number valid!');
} else {
  alert('Phone number invalid.');
}
```